# NSString select part go a string objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have problem with string. The string shows: `~00000000:termometr2: +26.9 st.C` and I want to use only this part: `+26.9 st.C` in my textfield.text.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to find the appropriate substring method yourself at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might help you:

```
NSArray *_array = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
[myTextField setText:[_array lastObject]]; // or any other component you want
```

Comment: It works extra. I made some changes but it's fine. Thanks again holes.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *fullStr = @"00000000:termometr2: +26.9 st.C";
NSArray *parts = [fullStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
textField.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[parts objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it this way, using the method **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:**:

```
NSString *originalString = @"~00000000:termometr2: +26.9 st.C";
NSString *filteredString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"~00000000:termometr2: " withString:@""];
```